# Using libgdx, how do I reset a PerspectiveCamera without resetting the view so I can correctly rotate the correct axis?

Tags: java, rotation, screen, libgdx, perspectivecamera

I'm using libgdx. I'm going through the basics so I'm just displaying a box using the following PerspectiveCameras to display a set of axis and a box:

```
environment = new Environment();

cam = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
cam.position.set(10f, 10f, 10f);
cam.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
cam.near = 0.1f;
cam.far = 300f;
cam.update();

zerocam = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
zerocam.position.set(10f, 10f, 10f);
zerocam.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
zerocam.near = 0.1f;
zerocam.far = 300f;
zerocam.update();
```

Using the follwing I'm able to rotate the box without rotating the axis:

This is in my RendererClass:

```
modelBatch.begin(zerocam);
modelBatch.render(drawAxis(0), environment);
modelBatch.render(drawAxis(1), environment);
modelBatch.render(drawAxis(2), environment);
modelBatch.end();

modelBatch.begin(cam);
modelBatch.render(drawBox(), environment);
modelBatch.end();

cam.update();
```

This is in my ScreenClass:

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new CameraInputController(cam));
```

As you can see it will rotate the `cam` PerspectiveCamera and not the `zerocam` PerspectiveCamera so the box rotates but the axis remain fixed. The problem is if I have dragged vertically so the box is laying on a side, dragging left/right will still rotate like a clock and not a merry-go-round. Hopefully that makes sense.

How can I utilize the following method of `public class ScreenClass implements Screen, InputProcessor` to correctly rotate the box.

```
touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer)
```

Basically when I drag left or right, I want the box to rotate left/right no matter what is actually happening to the cam.

I'm heading this direction: calling `rotateBox(int x, int y)` in the `RenderClass` from my `ScreenClass` to calculate how much to rotate.

```
public void rotateBox(int x, int y) {
    Vector3 difVector = cam.position.sub(zerocam.position);

    cam.rotateAround(new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f),
            difVector,
            1f);
}
```

This just gives me a difference of `cam` from `zerocam` but I feel this is the right direction. I think I just to somehow use the x and y values to calculate the direction to rotate and then somehow figure out what float value to apply to the specific axis.

Thanks